# N-Summation : How many ways to write N as a sum of distinct integers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Take N a positive integer. Here are my questions :
>
> 1. How many ways are there to write down $N$ as a sum of distinct positive integers ?
> 2. How many ways are there to write down $N$ as a sum of positive integers ?
> 3. What happens if we set the number of terms in the sum ?
> 4. What if we set a minimum value for the terms used in the sum ? A
>    maximum value ?

---

These were questions I asked my self this summer. Although I put lots of efforts into finding explicit formulas, I couldn't. I wonder if we there are ways to explicitly compute these numbers depending on $N$. If you have  links to any correlated works, I would be pleased to read them. Thank you.

Here, of course, we only consider non-zero integers.

Comment: If the order matters ($4 = 1 + 3$, $4 = 3+1$ considered different) than these are called compositions. If order does not matter, they're called partitions, which are rather more difficult to count (with no simple formula.)

Comment: [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @Jair Thanks to you I now have the power to learn about them ! Great !